# How Selenium Webdriver fires HTTP Requests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, httprequest

I am a beginner in Selenium RC and Selenium WebDriver. I am having difficulty in understanding the flow of Selenium WebDriver on how HTTP Requests are fired by WebDriver.

Here is my understanding:-

Selenium RC:-
Browser makes a  HTTP Request using a Proxy Handler, Proxy Handler establishes a HTTP Connection with Remote WebDriver using a HTTP Server, The Server sends a response Back to the Browser in the form of HTML or JSON(Based on the Request) and we can record our requests on a HAR file.

For WebDriver, Since there is no Proxy Handler, I want to know how a HTTP Connection is established between the Browser and WebDriver. I want to extend the Class which makes the HTTP Request, so that I can customize my HTTPRequest and record the HTTP Response from the HTTP Server and correspondingly I can store it in a HAR file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using a BrowserMob Proxy.. I did a small POC with BrowserMob Proxy, and HTTP requests are fired with them.. I was able to get the HAR file also by using browserMobProxy.getHar();